# Почему возвращает set()?

Tags: python

Почему возвращает set() при методе difference когда все данные одинаковы? и переменная должна была бы быть пустая?

Comment: `set()` - это и есть пустое множество. Почему не пустые фигурные скобки? Потому что пустые фигурные скобки - это `dict()`.

Comment: P.S. вообще нет такого понятия "пустая переменная". Разница (difference) между двумя одинаковыми множествами - пустое множество.

Answer (score 1):

А по-вашему, что должно возвращаться???
Откройте в конце концов учебник, на подсказках программистом не станешь и экзамен не сдашь !!!

```
set_1=set(['яблоко', 'вишня'])
set_2=set(['яблоко', 'вишня'])
set_3=set_1.difference(set_2)

print(set_3, type(set_3))
```

Результат:

```
set() <class 'set'>
```

Когда все данные одинаковые возвращает ПУСТОЙ объект типа set().

А когда разные

```
set_1=set(['яблоко', 'вишня','груша'])
set_2=set(['яблоко', 'вишня'])
set_3=set_1.difference(set_2)

print(set_3, type(set_3))
```

возвращается НЕ ПУСТОЙ объект типа set.

```
{'груша'} <class 'set'>
```

Comment: Достали вас видать студенты )  Всё же надо мягше как-то, хотя повод и есть )

Comment: @CrazyElf Ага :-) На самом деле - я их очень люблю, но при одном условии - они любят думать самостоятельно. А в данном случае  -  второй вопрос за день, ответ на который можно найти на первой странице учебника по теме. Ни "думать", ни "самостоятельно" не наблюдается.